# dependency (for sun.security.util) of SBT build

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using `SBT` to build my `Scala` project. I have also `Java` code in my project.

When I run the build I constantly get following error:

> error: package sun.security.util does not exist
>   [error] import sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier;

I understand that I need to declare dependency to the `sun.security.util`, but I don't know what is the dependency I should depend on?

My build.sbt contains:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.springframework" % "spring-dao" % 2.0.8",)
```

My JDK version is "1.7.0_25". I need to use the `sun.security.util` package. This [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) said it is not guaranteed in JDK. How can I declare the dependency to make it work? I mean, What is the name of dependency I should add?

Comment: What JDK/JVM are compiling this code on? Perhaps add the output of `javac -version` and `java -version` to the question.

Comment: This class belongs to the JDK but you shouldn't usually depend on it manually (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). Why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: @jrudolph, I said the reason in my question, because when I SBT build, I got error: package sun.security.util does not exist

Comment: You mean your code doesn't reference `sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier` itself? Can you put a reproduction of the issue somewhere?

Comment: I think it will be easier to help you if you can add some code on how to reproduce this.

Comment: I think to get help here you'll have to share minimized version of the project you are trying to build. Try to throw away as much as you can (source code, dependencies, plugins used) from your build (yet have the problem still be present) and share it, so we could figure out what causes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Packages in sun.* are not guaranteed to work everywhere. Thus, it is not recommended to use these packages, unless the JVM running your code is under your control.

Check out http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The package `sun.security.util` is from JDK, so you don't need to add dependency in your `build.sbt` file.

Check your environment.

Here is my environment, it works well.

**javac -version**
`javac 1.7.0_71`

---

**java -version**
`java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)`

---

**scalac -version**
`Scala compiler version 2.10.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`

---

**scala -version**
`Scala code runner version 2.10.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`

Comment: My question is though I have the environment, when I SBT build, I got error: package sun.security.util does not exist. Why is that? I know it is supposed to be part of JDK.